# Post file using httpclient fluent API

Tags: apache-httpclient-4.x

I always using httpclient fluent api to post messages because of the code is very clean.
example :

```
String html = Request.Post("URL")
             .connectTimeout(2000).socketTimeout(2000)
             .bodyForm(Form.form().add("type", "image").build(), Charset.forName("UTF8"))
             .execute().returnContent().asString();
```

After reading the httpclient document, I have found this:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
builder.setCharset(Charset.forName(CHARSET));
builder.addBinaryBody("media", bytes, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, fileName);
```

The question is how can I use fluent API to realize this function.

I find `.bodyFile(new File(""), ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` but I don`t know how to set the form param name of the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE)
        .setCharset(Charset.forName(CHARSET))
        .addBinaryBody("media", bytes, ContentType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA, fileName)
        .build();
String html = Request.Post("URL")
        .connectTimeout(2000)
        .socketTimeout(2000)
        .body(entity)
        .execute().returnContent().asString();
```